# My php header tag will not redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I've tried doing my research and it doesn't look like I'm coming up successful.  I made sure there is no content being printed out to the screen before my header tags.

This page is taking information given from the form in the previous login page and using that information to determine which page the user should be redirected to.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like any of my header tags are redirecting to anything, it just stays on this php page.

To debug, I have echo'd each scenario (logged in, out, wrong pw) and each scenario works, but obviously when I echo'd the redirect wouldn't work.  I just wanted to test that the information was being transmitted correctly.

Can anyone else help and give me an outsider's perspective?

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconnect.php');
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT password FROM artists WHERE email='$email'";
$passwordMatch = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($passwordMatch);
if($row[0] == $password){
    $query = "SELECT active FROM artists WHERE email = '$email'";
    $active = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $active = mysqli_fetch_array($active);
    $active = $active[0];
    if ( $active == 0 ){
        header('Location: validate.php');
    }
    else{
        header('Location: artistHome.php'); //redirect to user home page and update session
        $_SESSION['user']= $email;
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: login.php");
    $_SESSION['error']= 'Invalid Password';
}
?>
```

Comment: You should check the error log and / or enable error display. That will tell you if you have a `headers already sent` problem.

Comment: assigning the session after header is not going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were about thousands of posts like this one over here.Get rid of php closing tag `?>` and whitespaces, html, blank lines before php opening tag `<?php`. Also check if there is no output before :

```
header("Location:");
```

Like `print`,`var_dump`, `echo` and so on.

Also check your `if` condition, maybe you are just skipping it.

If you `include`,`include_once`,`require_once` or `require` check all the things above in the included files too.

To narrow a circle of the things to correct look into your php `error_log` and provide us with error description.

Comment: I have checked the PHP error log and it looks like my dbconnect was sending output to the screen.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: login.php");` will always fail if **anything** is returned to the browser before it. That includes whitespace, or even errors PHP are returning. Make sure **nothing** is being returned before the `header` function is used.